# Which identity has been used here? $\sin(3t)\cos(10t) = 0.5\,(\sin (13t) + \sin (-7t))$

Tags: trigonometry

I have this written down in my notes, but I cannot remember how it came about:

> $$\sin(3t)\cos(10t) = 0.5\,(\sin (13t) + \sin (-7t))$$

Comment: No one. As it is written it is not an identity.

Comment: It can't be - the periods of the two functions are different. The left-hand side is $ 0.5 \cdot \sin 6t$

Comment: I entered a wrong number. The correction has been made

Comment: @user2883071, See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the [product to sum formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities).

$$\sin(a)\cos(b) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)\right).$$

Comment: There are a lot of trig identities that it becomes hard to keep track of them in your head. So make sure you can prove the formula to yourself. It'll make it easier to remember!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remember the complex forms of $sin$ and $cos$ which from them you could easily extract most of their identities, specifically $$\begin{array}{c}\sin x = \frac{{{e^{ix}} - {e^{ - ix}}}}{{2i}}\\\cos x = \frac{{{e^{ix}} + {e^{ - ix}}}}{2}\end{array}$$ so that for your question, we have $$\begin{array}{c}\sin (3t)\cos (10t) = \frac{{{e^{3it}} - {e^{ - 3it}}}}{{2i}}\frac{{{e^{10it}} + {e^{ - 10it}}}}{2}\\ = \frac{{{e^{13it}} + {e^{ - 7it}} - {e^{7it}} - {e^{ - 13it}}}}{{4i}}\\ = \frac{{{e^{13it}} - {e^{ - 13it}}}}{{4i}} + \frac{{{e^{ - 7it}} - {e^{7it}}}}{{4i}}\\ = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\sin (13t) + \sin ( - 7t)} \right)\end{array}$$Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Now it makes sense how they got it, Thanks!

Comment: This actually helped me out in another question too. so thanks again!

Comment: @user2883071 Your welcome. Glad it helped ;)